# How to find smalles n that satisfies inequality

Tags: inequality

I wish to find the lowest $n_0$ such that $n\geq n_0$ for:
$$n^2\leq 2^n \leq n!$$

I tried splitting this into two different inequalities and then trying to solve each one and intersect their solutions. However, I have been unable to solve either of them, so I am really stuck.

Any hints would be very appreciated.
EDIT: $n$ has to be a positive integer.

Comment: You could try the first 10 integers and then make a conjecture.

Comment: If you followed Martin R's advice, you should've found 2 solutions of $n^2=2^n$. Will they ever be equal for higher $n$? For the $2^n \le n!$ part, try induction.